# Understanding of the classpath and the classloader

Tags: java, maven, classpath, classloader

The root of my misunderstanding concerns the classpath or the classloader to me but I'll depict it in the context with my first steps with OpenEJB.

I was playing with OpenEJB embedded and I faced some strange issues.
I am using maven to pull dependencies and one of it is a jar containing all my EJBs.

My application simply creates an EJB container and try to lookup one of my `@Singleton` which is contained in the dependencies.

**case 1)**

When I'm launching the `main` from Netbeans, which relies on maven (`exec-maven-plugin`) everything is working fine, I can lookup my bean.
It uses this command line :

`mvn -e "-Dexec.args=-classpath %classpath com.app.Main" -Dexec.executable=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk/bin/java org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec`

**case 2)**

If I try to package my application as a jar with dependencies in a specific folder `lib` my EJBs are not found.

Here is a part of my pom.xml to create the MANIFEST.MF and put my dependencies in a `lib` folder.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <index>true</index>
            <manifest>
                <classpathPrefix>./lib/</classpathPrefix>
                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                <mainClass>com.app.Main</mainClass>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I'm running the application this way :
`java -jar target/app.jar`

Now I'm wondering WHY in **case 1** I can find my EJB's and not in **case 2**.

I added this piece of code :

```
    ClassLoader cl = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();

    URL[] urls = ((URLClassLoader)cl).getURLs();

    for (URL url: urls){
        System.out.println(url.getFile());
    }
```

Which shows me in **case 1** all my dependencies but only the current jar in **case 2**

When opening the `MANIFEST.MF` from the generated jar all the dependencies are correctly appended to the `Class-Path`.

Can someone clarify this to me ?

Comment: Are all your dependencies placed into the folder `./lib/` directly?

Comment: Yes, there are 89 dependencies including the one containing my EJBs, during my tests it is stored in `${project.build.directory}/lib`, I'm using `maven-dependency-plugin` to fill it

Comment: Does the OpenEJB documentation specify that it observes the `Class-Path` of the jar manifest? I don't know of any EJB server that looks at the jar manifest, though I haven't used one in quite a while. Usually the server has its own configuration structure, like some XML files, and the classpath is specified there.